# Radiobuton list click show hide label control

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to show/hide Label control if the Radio button List value is 'N'. The code works fine but when I uncheck the radio button the Label control doesn't hide. Also I am using Jquery mousedown event to clear the selection. Please suggest.

```
var radioList = "#<%= radioLst1.ClientID %>";
  var lblID = document.getElementById('<%=LblIDNumber.ClientID%>');

    $(radioList + " input:radio").click(function (e) {
        if ($('#<%= radioLst1.ClientID %> input:checked').val() == "N") {
            lblID.style.display = $(this).attr("checked") ? 'inline' : 'none';
        }
        else {
            lblID.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
```

I am using the following code to clear the selection of the radio button list.

```
 $(radioList + " input:radio").mousedown(function (e) {
        if ($(this).attr("checked") == true) {
            setTimeout("$('input[id=" + $(this).attr('id') + "]').removeAttr('checked');", 200);
            lblID.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    });

                <asp:Label ID="LblIDNumber" style="display:none" runat="server">Number</asp:Label>

                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radioLst1" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="U">Unknown</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="N">Not Applicable</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be attaching an event to your `radioLst1.ClientID` this will get translated to a table by asp.net

You can simplify the process like this

```
var lblID = $('#mylabel');


 $('input:radio').on('click', function(){

   if($(this).val() == 'N')
   {
   lblID.hide();
  }else{
  lblID.show();
  }       

 });
```

and you controls

```
<label id="mylabel">This is a label</label>

 <input id="radioLst1_0" type="radio" value="U" name="radioLst1">
  <label for="radioLst1_0">Unknown</label>

 <input id="radioLst1_1" type="radio" value="N" name="radioLst1">
     <label for="radioLst1_1">Not Applicable</label>
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xnV9t/)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap all of this into an UpdatePanel. Then fire code behind events for each button click (you can subscribe them all to the same event) and then bind the label to the button's .Checked property. The UpdatePanel will make everything async.

I suggest this as an alternative to javascript/jquery. It'll be a little cleaner and easier to manage. A bit more markup in the beginning but then making changes will be pretty easy.